# common rows between 2 text file in linux command line

Tags: awk

I have 2 text files. the 1st one is like this:

```
DB  41533499    41533500    14
CD  41533500    41533501    3
AR  41533504    41533505    5
DR  41533506    41533507    3
AR  41533508    41533509    1
AR  48743349    48743350    1
```

and the 2nd one looks like this:

```
DB  41533400    41533600
DR  41533300    41533800
AR  41533200    41533800
AR  48743100    48743983
```

the difference between 2nd and 3rd columns is 1 which means that is a point. I would like to make a new file in which the 1st column is common between 2 files and also the range of 2nd and 3rd columns in file 2 is in the range of 2nd and 3rd columns in file2. here is the expected output:

```
DB  41533400    41533600    41533499    41533500    14
DR  41533300    41533800    41533506    41533507    3
AR  41533200    41533800    41533508    41533509    1
AR  48743100    48743983    48743349    48743350    1
```

I am trying to do in linux command line and wrote the following but did not get what I want:

```
awk '{print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" }' file2.txt '{print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 }' file1.txt > output.txt
```

do you know how to fix it?

Comment: explain, why this entry `AR  41533504    41533505    5` should be skipped?

Comment: because there is no corresponding row in the 2nd file

Comment: that sounds doubtful ...

Comment: `AR  41533504    41533505` fits in `AR  41533200    41533800` in file2 based on your explained logic.  Perhaps there is another constraint like uniqueness?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one for GNU awk but I share [the same question with @RomanPerekhrest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47810815/common-rows-between-2-text-file-in-linux-command-line/47811619#comment82583567_47810815) about the record `AR 41533504 41533505 5`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{
    a[$1][$2]=$3; next
}
($1 in a) {
    for(i in a[$1])
        if($2>=i && $3 <= a[$1][i])
            print $1,i,a[$1][i],$2,$3,$4
}' file2 file1
DB 41533400 41533600 41533499 41533500 14
AR 41533200 41533800 41533504 41533505 5
DR 41533300 41533800 41533506 41533507 3
AR 41533200 41533800 41533508 41533509 1
AR 48743100 48743983 48743349 48743350 1
```

Answer (score 0):

based on my free interpretation of the requirements based on the missing row

with pipes instead of a single `awk` script (already answered)

```
$ join <(sort file2) <(sort file1) | # sort and join on key (1st field)
  awk '$2<$4 && $3>$5'             | # apply within range logic
  sort -k6n                        | # sort ascending based on last field
  awk '!a[$2]++'                   | # pick first instance of 2nd field (the lowest) 
  tac                                # reverse to be in descending order


DB 41533400 41533600 41533499 41533500 14
DR 41533300 41533800 41533506 41533507 3
AR 48743100 48743983 48743349 48743350 1
AR 41533200 41533800 41533508 41533509 1
```